# why the virtual inheritance seems don't work?

Tags: c++

when I read the book "Inside the C++ Object Model",it shows a sample like this

```
class A{};
class B:public virtual A{};
class C:public virtual A{};
class D:public B,public C{};
```

when I use `sizeof` on D,the result is 16,but the book said it should be 12 or 8.
My IDE is vs2022

Comment: Your book seems to make assumptions about particular platforms or compilers. Get a better book.

Comment: If you are referring to "Inside the C++ Object Model" by Lippman, that book is from 1996 from what I can tell. It was written even before standardization of C++ was completed. Whatever it is assuming about the architecture is almost surely out-dated. In particular x86-64 wasn't around at the time. Also, assuming I got the correct book, I don't know why you would tag C++11, which certainly isn't mentioned in that book.

Comment: The book doesn't say anything like that. It says "obviously in part that depends on the compiler being used" and also it says that "on my correspondent's machine the pointer is 4 bytes".

Answer (score 0):

No, it's correct D inherited from two structs and two of them have pointers to A.

inheritance and composition have some redundancy may be because of this Rust remove inheritance in, Rust version I see your code same as this.

````
struct B{ 
  A *base;// because of virtual inheritance base is A*, not A
};
struct C{ 
  A *base;// because of virtual inheritance base is A*, not A
};
struct D{
  B base1,// because of typical inheritance base is B, not B*
  C base2;
}```
````